# How to access/escape PHP object member with a $ character in its name?

Tags: php

I'm decoding some JSON (from the Youtube data API) with json_decode and it gives me an object that looks like this when var_dump()ed:

```
object(stdClass)[29]
  public 'type' => string 'text' (length=4)
  public '$t' => string 'Miley and Mandy! KCA VIDEO WINNERS' (length=34)
```

How can I access the $t member?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
$member = '$t';
$obj->$member
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use the second argument of json_decode

```
$data = json_decode($text, true);
echo $data['$t'];
```

Answer (score 0):

$t will only interpreted as a variable reference when used outside of quotes, or within double quotes ("$t"). Strings enclosed in single quotes ('$t') are not parsed for variable references.

```
echo $data['$t'];
```

Will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use: `$obj->{'$t'}`.

Found that information in [PHP documentation about Objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting).